# Faster Upload large scale excel(xlx and xlsx) file into mysql using php and spout

Tags: php, mysql, excel

Hope everyone is fine. I am facing a problem while upload a large excel file. The file contain 150+k  rows. When i run the php script, after a while it stops execution and cann't upload the data . i used the below code for uploading.

```
require_once('vendor/excel_reader2.php');
require_once('vendor/SpreadsheetReader.php');

if (isset($_POST["import"]))
{
    ini_set('max_execution_time',0);    
    $allowedFileType = ['application/vnd.ms-excel','text/xls','text/xlsx','application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet'];  
    if(in_array($_FILES["file"]["type"],$allowedFileType)){

        $targetPath = 'uploads/'.$_FILES['file']['name'];
        move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], $targetPath);

        $Reader = new SpreadsheetReader($targetPath);

        $sheetCount = count($Reader->sheets());
        for($i=0;$i<$sheetCount;$i++)
        {

            $Reader->ChangeSheet($i);

            foreach ($Reader as $Row)
            {
                $data[]=$Row; 
                //insert from here              
            }



         }

         //echo implode(',',$data);
         echo $data[1][0];
         echo "<pre>"; print_r($data); echo "</pre>";


  }
  else
  { 
        $type = "error";
        $message = "Invalid File Type. Upload Excel File.";
  }

}
```

Comment: So the SQL. Show the table structures. Show the mysql configuration. For large files perhaps upload them and put the processing of them in an background job because your web server will have a maximum time. Perhaps output some progress output during the upload process.

Answer (score 0):

Inserting one row at a time is slow.  Save them in an array and after your loops, go through the array taking say a 100 at a time and insert those with a single insert statement.